# Options not working with React Owl Carousel 2

Tags: reactjs, owl-carousel-2

I followed the documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-owl-carousel2 and tried to integrated owl carousel 2. Its an image carousel. All the images are appearing as one side even if I changed the items option values. Below is my code. Can any one please take a look why it not working.

```
import React from 'react';
import OwlCarousel from 'react-owl-carousel2';  
import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css';  
import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css';  

export default class CalendarView extends React.Component{
    render(){
        const options = {
            items: 1,
            nav: true,
            rewind: true,
            autoplay: true
        };
        
        return(
            <div>
                <div>This is Calendar View</div>
                <div className='container-fluid' >            
                
                <OwlCarousel className="owl-theme" options={options} margin={4}>
                    <div>
                        <img className="img" src= {'../assets/img/completed_case_1.png'} height="250px"/>
                        <img className="img" src= {'../assets/img/completed_case_2.png'}  height="250px"/>
                        <img className="img" src= {'../assets/img/completed_case_3.png'}  height="250px"/>
                        <img className="img" src= {'../assets/img/gallery_4.png'} height="250px"/>
                        <img className="img" src= {'../assets/img/gallery_5.png'} height="250px"/>
                    </div>      
                </OwlCarousel>  

             </div>
            </div>
            
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the output am getting

[image]

Answer (score 0):

change `<div />` tag wrap on each image instead of wrap all image.

```
<div><img src="" /></div>
<div><img src="" /></div>
<div><img src="" /></div>
<div><img src="" /></div>
```

Comment: I tried to wrap each image with a div but they started appearing one below the other and all the divs have the class as "active". I am nit sure if the owl carousel css is working, Do you know how we can check if the owl carousel css files are loaded in Developer Tools or in any other way please.